# struts2 validation framework requires result input

Tags: validation, input, struts

In my project with struts2, I don't use validation framework, and no action methods return "input" in my Action class. Here is my configuration snippet,

```
    <action name="searchTracker" class="searchAction" method="searchTracker">
        <result name="success">/jsp/searchTracker.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/jsp/searchTracker.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/jsp/searchTracker.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Here is the action class

```
 public String searchTracker(){

    this.clearErrorsAndMessages();

    List<File> files = fileManager.retrieveFiles(patchNumBySearch);
    if(files == null){
        this.setTrackers(null);
        addActionError("This patch number doesn't exist. Please choose another one !");
        return ERROR;
    } else {
        if (files.size() == 0) {
            addActionError("This patch doesn't include any tracker. Please create tracker or choose another patch");
            return ERROR;
            }
        else {
            List<Tracker> trackers = commonUtils.convertToTrackers(files);
            this.setTrackers(trackers);
        }
    }
        return SUCCESS;
}
```

If I remove input result, it will throw exception, like this

```
     "No result defined for action SearchTrackerAction and result input"
```

and if i check back end log, it shows 
       "2011-11-07 00:09:13,841 DEBUG

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.debug:68 - Errors on action com.harris.northstar.dbadesk.action.SearchTrackerAction@1d07b41, returning result name 'input'"
```

Why it invokes DefaultWorkflowInterceptor and return result name input?

If I put back input result in configuration, the exception is gone. But If Action goes to error firstly, it won't go to sucess again even I set break point, it won't go into that method `searchTracker()` after that.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be caused by a type conversion error; without knowing more about what you're sending in, it's difficult to help beyond that.

If you remove the "workflow" interceptor, S2 will stop checking for errors on the action. You may also need to remove the type conversion interceptor, but workflow should be enough. If you're not using any validation, you may as well remove that interceptor as well.

Comment: @user1006080 You'd need to define your own [interceptor stack](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/interceptor-configuration.html) and use it as your default stack. I'd just copy the `defaultStack` and try removing just "workflow" first.

Comment: and then I have to add this interceptor stack into my action configuration <action> <interceptor-ref name="dcmStack" /><result/></action> ?

Comment: @user1006080 You *could* add it to a specific action, with the understanding that the rest of your actions would use whatever the default stack is, and the action you configure it on would call only the interceptors/stacks defined within that action's configuration. I'd find it a little weird that you'd want it turned off only for one action.

Comment: but how to make it works for all the actions instead of only one?

Comment: @user1006080 [The docs are your friend.](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-configure-an-interceptor-to-be-used-with-every-action.html)

Comment: I don't think remove workflow interceptor is smart way to fix the problem. My question is why workflow interceptor is invoked and make complain about input result missing when I remove result input in my action configuration. But this action method doesn't return input at all. (I just add my action class)

Comment: @user1006080 It doesn't make any difference what your action returns. The workflow interceptor is executed *before* your action is executed. If there are any errors on the action, like from validation or a type conversion error, the *interceptor* returns "input", and your action isn't executed at all.

Comment: @user1006080 To answer *why* the workflow interceptor is invoked: because it's in the default interceptor stack, and every interceptor in the stack is invoked in the order they're listed in the stack configuration, unless an interceptor "breaks the chain" and returns early. Please read some of the S2 docs to see how the framework actually works; it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @user1006080 I don't think removing the interceptor is a good idea, but if you don't want to deal with conversion errors, our you can't figure out why S2 believes it needs to go back to the input result, you don't have many options. You could configure the input result name so it doesn't specifically need an "input" result, too.